# Save JPG with compression in MonoMac

Tags: compression, jpeg, monomac

This is my MonoMac code for saving a JPG with compression. It's pretty simple, just set the `NSImageCompressionFactor` apparently. Shame it doesn't work.

```
public void SaveImage(NSImage MyNSImage,string Location, float Quality) 
{
    NSBitmapImageRep BRep=(NSBitmapImageRep)MyNSImage.Representations()[0]; 
    NSDictionary Dic= NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(new NSNumber(Quality),new NSString("NSImageCompressionFactor")); 
    NSData D=BRep.RepresentationUsingTypeProperties(NSBitmapImageFileType.Jpeg,Dic); 
    System.IO.Stream S=D.AsStream(); 
    SaveStream(Location,S); 
    S.Dispose(); 
    D.Dispose(); 
} 

//This save function works fine so ignore it.
void SaveStream(string FileName, Stream Source) 
{ 
    FileStream FS=File.OpenWrite(FileName); 
    int Read=0; 
    byte[] Buffer=new byte[1024]; 
    Source.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin); 
    do{ 
        Read = Source.Read(Buffer, 0, 1024); 
        FS.Write(Buffer, 0, Read); 
    }while(Read>0); 
    FS.Close(); 
}
```

It always saves as 100% though, what am I doing wrong? Hope some clever person knows the answer.

Answer (score 0):

There's a general design pattern with all these property dictionaries: their keys are *string constants* (variables with that name), not strings and the Objective C runtime matches them by address, not by value.

For instance, in your case, `NSImageCompressionFactor` is declared as

```
NSString *NSImageCompressionFactor;
```

in Objective C and it's initialized to some constant string (that could be anything, in theory), it's basically a pointer to some opaque value.

When populating the property dictionary in Objective C, you use the name of the variable (ie. you simply write `NSImageCompressionFactor`) instead of creating a new string instance (`@"NSImageCompressionFactor"`).

In MonoMac, we create string properties for these dictionary keys, for instance see [MonoMac.Foundation.NSUrl.ContentAccessDateKey](http://api.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aMonoMac.Foundation.NSUrl.ContentAccessDateKey).

However, they're missing in a few places (your bitmap image properties were one of these, I just added them to `NSBitmapImageRep` in [monomac commit 115f1eb](https://github.com/mono/monomac/commit/115f1eb120a2dfd14c4524e63fe55645abcda04b)).  If anyone finds more missing properties in future, please simply file a bug report at `bugzilla.xamarin.com`.

There's also a workaround if you're using an older version of MonoMac.  In the generator input file ([monomac/src/appkit.cs](https://github.com/mono/monomac/blob/115f1eb120a2dfd14c4524e63fe55645abcda04b/src/appkit.cs#L1120)), these are declared like this:

```
[Field ("NSImageCompressionMethod")]
NSString CompressionMethod { get; }

[Field ("NSImageCompressionFactor")]
NSString CompressionFactor { get; }
```

The generator then emits:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
static readonly IntPtr AppKit_libraryHandle = Dlfcn.dlopen (Constants.AppKitLibrary, 0);
[CompilerGenerated]
static NSString _CompressionMethod;
public static NSString CompressionMethod {
    get {
        if (_CompressionMethod == null)
            _CompressionMethod = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant (AppKit_libraryHandle, "NSImageCompressionMethod");
        return _CompressionMethod;
    }
}
[CompilerGenerated]
static NSString _CompressionFactor;
public static NSString CompressionFactor {
    get {
        if (_CompressionFactor == null)
            _CompressionFactor = Dlfcn.GetStringConstant (AppKit_libraryHandle, "NSImageCompressionFactor");
        return _CompressionFactor;
    }
}
```

You can simply do the same somewhere in your app.

**Update**

Let's first start by looking an an example in Objective C (full sample [here](https://github.com/baulig/Provcon-Faust/commit/5dd4d76199afd503b7aad06f99c9ba0aac37c8c2), the image is from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aNeptune.jpg)):

```
- (NSData *)saveImage:(NSImage *)image location:(NSString *)location quality:(float)quality {
    NSBitmapImageRep *imageRep = [[image representations] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:quality], NSImageCompressionFactor, nil];

    NSData *data = [imageRep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:dict];
    printf("DATA: %ld\n", [data length]);
    return data;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *resDir = [[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Contents"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Resources"];
    NSString *filePath = [resDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Neptune.jpg"];

    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

    [self saveImage:image location:@"output.jpg" quality:0.0];
    [self saveImage:image location:@"output.jpg" quality:0.25];
    [self saveImage:image location:@"output.jpg" quality:0.5];
    [self saveImage:image location:@"output.jpg" quality:1.0];
}
```

Now let's turn this into a MonoMac application (full sample [here](https://github.com/baulig/Provcon-Faust/commit/dbcc9f1f4a6041921565bcbc8b6eee8d66fd437a)):

```
public override void FinishedLaunching (NSObject notification)
{
    mainWindowController = new MainWindowController ();
    mainWindowController.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront (this);

    var path = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, "Contents", "Resources");
    var filePath = Path.Combine (path, "Neptune.jpg");

    var image = new NSImage (filePath);
    Console.WriteLine (image);

    SaveImage (image, "output.jpg", 0.0f);
    SaveImage (image, "output.jpg", 0.25f);
    SaveImage (image, "output.jpg", 0.5f);
    SaveImage (image, "output.jpg", 1.0f);
}

public void SaveImage (NSImage image, string location, float quality) 
{
    var brep = (NSBitmapImageRep)image.Representations ()[0];

    var dict = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey (NSNumber.FromFloat (quality), NSBitmapImageRep.CompressionFactor);

    var data = brep.RepresentationUsingTypeProperties (NSBitmapImageFileType.Jpeg, dict);
    Console.WriteLine (data.Length);
}
```

This prints the same sizes like the Objective C sample, so this actually works.

Comment: I've tried adding:

NSString *NSImageCompressionFactor;

But I just get an error.

Error CS0208: Cannot take the address of, get the size of, or declare a pointer to a managed type `MonoMac.Foundation.NSString' (CS0208)


NSBitmapImageRep.NSImageCompressionFactor

doesn't exist either.

I'm using C# in MonoMac, what am I missing here?

Comment: It is declared as `NSString *NSImageCompressionFactor` in Objective C, not C#.

To use this in C#, you need to use `Dlfnc.GetStringConstant` like I showed above.

This is the auto-generated file from [monomac commit 115f1e](https://github.com/mono/monomac/commit/115f1eb120a2dfd14c4524e63fe55645abcda04b): https://raw.github.com/gist/4025571/2a4dafb1c29ebfda50014b4aed0f454202c0430b/gistfile1

Comment: I've added another answer to this question, I'm getting closer, is there any chance you could have a look at it?

Comment: Sure, let's start with getting a working example in Objective C.  Which compression factor did you use ?  I first made the mistake of using numbers greater than 1.0.  Will update my answer with my Objective C sample, then test whether it works with Mono.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your example, it's basically the same as mine except that I'm printing the `NSData`'s size instead of storing it on the disk.

Have you tried using a number between 0 and 1 as compression factor ?

Comment: Sadly still 100%. I'm using 0.05f as the factor. The only thing different is NSBitmapImageRep.CompressionFactor. Do you know when/how I can get this value?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'm getting closer but it still saves at 100%, any more suggestions?:

```
public void SaveImage(NSImage MyNSImage,string Location, float Quality) 
{

            NSBitmapImageRep BRep=(NSBitmapImageRep)MyNSImage.Representations()[0];
            NSDictionary Dic= NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(new NSNumber(Quality),NSImageCompressionFactor);
            NSData D=BRep.RepresentationUsingTypeProperties(NSBitmapImageFileType.Jpeg,Dic);
            System.IO.Stream S=D.AsStream();
            SaveStream(Location,S);
            S.Dispose();
            D.Dispose();

    }
    static readonly IntPtr AppKit_libraryHandle = MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn.dlopen (MonoMac.Constants.AppKitLibrary, 0);

    static NSString _NSImageCompressionFactor;
    public static NSString NSImageCompressionFactor {
        get {
            if (_NSImageCompressionFactor == null) {
                _NSImageCompressionFactor= MonoMac.ObjCRuntime.Dlfcn.GetStringConstant (AppKit_libraryHandle, "NSImageCompressionFactor");
            }
            return _NSImageCompressionFactor;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I eventually gave up tryting to get this to work as above.

I found this C# jpeg encoder.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83225/A-Simple-JPEG-Encoder-in-C

You need to correct one line as specified in the comments.